# Как заставить работать bind9 с "_" в CNAME?

Tags: debian, bind, cname

Нужно добавить в `zone` запись вида:
`_MD5HASH. IN CNAME ID.`
При попытке перезагрузки `rndc reload site.ru`:

```
dns_master_load: /etc/bind/zones/site.ru.named:12: _MD5HASH.site.ru: CNAME and other data
zone site.ru/IN: loading from master file /etc/bind/zones/site.ru.named failed: CNAME and other dat
```

Добавил в `zone.conf` - `check-names ignore;`, не помогло:

```
zone "site.ru" IN {
    type master;
    check-names ignore;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/site.ru.named";
    allow-update { none; };
};
```

Добавил в `named.conf.options` -

```
check-names master ignore;
check-mx-cname ignore;
check-srv-cname ignore;
```

:

```
options {
 directory "/var/cache/bind";
 dnssec-validation auto;
 auth-nxdomain no;
 allow-query { any; };
 version "No info"; 
 listen-on { ip1; ip2; };
 allow-recursion { none; };
 allow-transfer { ip3; };

 check-names master ignore;
 check-mx-cname ignore;
 check-srv-cname ignore;
};
```

Не помогло.

Идеи кончились, что ещё можно сделать?

uname -a

```
Linux dns1 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.130-2 (2018-10-27) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

named -V

```
BIND 9.10.3-P4-Debian <id:ebd72b3>
built by make with '--prefix=/usr' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc/bind' '--with-python=python3' '--localstatedir=/' '--enable-threads' '--enable-largefile' '--with-libtool' '--enable-shared' '--enable-static' '--with-gost=no' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-gssapi=/usr' '--with-gnu-ld' '--with-geoip=/usr' '--with-atf=no' '--enable-ipv6' '--enable-rrl' '--enable-filter-aaaa' '--enable-native-pkcs11' '--with-pkcs11=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/softhsm/libsofthsm2.so' '--with-randomdev=/dev/urandom' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/bind9-zVMG3I/bind9-9.10.3.dfsg.P4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -DNO_VERSION_DATE -DDIG_SIGCHASE' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' 'CPPFLAGS=-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2'
compiled by GCC 6.3.0 20170516
compiled with OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
linked to OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
compiled with libxml2 version: 2.9.4
linked to libxml2 version: 20904
```

**UPD:**

```
$TTL 86400
@               IN      SOA     ns1.site.com. it.site.com. (
                                2019050906      ; serial
                                14400           ; refresh
                                7200            ; retry
                                4320000         ; expiration
                                86400           ; minimum (1 day)
)
                IN      NS      ns1.site.com.
                IN      NS      ns2.site.com.
_MD5HASH IN CNAME ID.comodoca.com.
                IN      A       ip
*               IN      A       ip
yamail-aaa     IN      CNAME   mail.yandex.ru.
@                       IN      MX      10      mx.yandex.ru.
mail._domainkey         IN      TXT     ("v=DKIM1; k=rsa; t=s; p=xxxx"
                                        "yyyy"
                                        "zzzz"
                                        "xxxx")
@                       IN      TXT     "v=spf1 redirect=_spf.yandex.net"

                        IN      TXT     yandex-verification: fff
```

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/834679/is-underscore-illegal-in-a-cname-record и RFC 2872 is a perfect counter to the myth that "_" is non-standard. The RFC is a standards track RFC, and describes SRV records. One of the authors is Paul Vixie, the original programmer of BIND.

Comment: 1. точки уберите: `_MD5HASH IN CNAME ID`. 2. приложите весь зонный файл.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin 1. убрал точку после `_MD5HASH`, после `ID` не могу, т.к. значение `CNAME` не должно содержать имя моего домена. 2. Сделал UPD вопроса.

Comment: @0-LevelUNIXMonk оно понятно, что в RFC не стандартизировано, я об этом всё утро читаю, для этого есть обход с параметром `check-names`, но что-то он не работает. И такая запись мне нужна для подтверждения `SSL-сертификата`.

Comment: Хотя судя по документации: https://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind/9.10.3-P4/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#options , `check-names` не имеет отношения к `CNAME` =/

Comment: 1. если `ip` — это просто подмана реального ip-адреса, то синтаксис вполне валиден. 2. если ошибка «*CNAME and other data*» всё равно присутствует, значит имя `_md5hash.ваш.домен.` определено где-то ещё.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin 1. да, просто подмена 2. вот не знаю где: `/etc/bind# grep -r "_MD5HASH" ./
./zones/site.ru.named`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, сейчас попробовал в конец зоны добавить и всё заработало:  `client ip#34867 (site.ru): transfer of 'site.ru/IN': AXFR-style IXFR started (serial 2019050907)`
`client ip#34867 (site.ru): transfer of 'site.ru/IN': AXFR-style IXFR ended`. Спрашивается, и что это было?